# create pseudo shell for a command

Tags: bash, shell, git

I feel like this should be straighforward to some degree...

Basically, for some command, I want to be able to invoke another command that will scope all params to that command. so...

```
git commit -am "test"
```

would become...

```
./shell_comand git
>commit -am "test"
>status
```

so, obviously things like autocomplete and whatnot wouldn't work, but I would expect otherwise this should be doable to some degree? I'm just not quite clear on how...

Answer (score 1):

I assume this should be doable in `git` itself, but since I'm no git expert I would use at shell functions. In a `sh`-compatible one (e.g. `bash`) you can easily write a function called `git` which will be invoked instead of the `git` binary (be careful to use full path to the binary inside of the function - or `command git` in BASH - to prevent unwanted recursion):

```bsh
function git () {
    case "$1" in
    "commit")
        # do your stuff
        /path/to/git ...
        ;;
     *)
        # call git binary with the same arguments
        /path/to/git "$@"
        ;;
}
```

You could use just command aliasing (`alias`), but functions give you way more flexibility.

As for the completion, check your shell completion functionality (for `bash` look for `complete` in the man page) - it's certainly possible to make it work and it doesn't even have to be too complicated.

Comment: Instead of `/path/to/git` you could write `command git`

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to define aliases for every git command. You could still run ordinary shell commands; if this is not desired, set `PATH` to a nonexistent directory. If you want to run the shell command and not the git command, put a backslash before the command (e.g. `\rm foo` to remove a file).

```
git_commands=$(COLUMNS=2 git --help --all | sed -n -e '1,/^----/d' -e '1,/^$/p')
for c in $git_commands; do
  alias "$c=git $c"
done
```

In zsh, you'll even have completion if you have the `complete_aliases` option set. I don't know about bash.